# Compare content of two files (diff)

Tags: bash, diff

What I'm trying to do is to compare the content of two different files. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but things I searched online regarding diff command didn't work.

For example if fileA content is this:

```
AAA:111
BBB:222
CCC:333
```

And fileB content is:

```
AAA:111
BBB:222
```

All I want to see as an output is the difference which is CCC:333. No "<" no ">", just plainly CCC:333. I want to use this later in the bash script I'm working on.

Also would it matter if those files were reversed? I mean if it was fileB containing CCC:333?

I don't know if it matters, but the files I'm working on are MAC addresses.

Is the diff command I was trying to use case sensitive?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. All the lines in file A which are not in file B? All the lines in *either* file which is not in the other file? Does order matter?

Comment: `sort fileA fileB | uniq -u`?

Comment: If the files are sorted you can use `comm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `diff` options as follows :

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' fileA fileB
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else was looking for those answers I only wanted to add that they both work!

The sort and uniq solution by Cyrus will show you differences in those two files (if the difference would be that they both have lines aaa and bbb, but only one would have xxx and the other had yyy, it would print out those two lines xxx and yyy).

The diff command solution by Philippe can give you different output because it depends if you put fileA first then fileB or if you will put fileB first and then fileA.
Test it yourself.

Correct me if I'm wrong please!

Thank you for your help.